# период времени между датами в соответствии с измерением

Tags: javascript

Функция принимает 3 параметра - дата1 (string) - дата2 (string) - измерение ('days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds').
Не могу понять как сделать правильно. В коде ошибки.

```js
'use strict';

function durationBetweenDates(firstDate, secondDate, dimensionBetween) {
  const firstDate = new Date();
  const secondDate = new Date();
  const millisecondsDiff = secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();
  
  if (dimensionBetween === 'seconds') {
    const secondsType = millisecondsDiff / 1000;
    return secondsType;
  }
  
  if (dimensionBetween === 'minutes') {
    const minutesType = Math.ceil(millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 60));
    return minutesType;
  }
  
  if (dimensionBetween === 'hours') {
    const hoursType = millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 3600);
    return hoursType;
  }
  
  if (dimensionBetween === 'days') {
    const daysType = millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    return daysType;
  } else {
    return console.log('Not Found');
  }
  
  return durationBetweenDates;
}

console.log(durationBetweenDates('02 Aug 1985', '03 Aug 1985', 'seconds'));
//return '86400 seconds'
console.log(durationBetweenDates('31 Jan 2022', '03 Feb 2021', 'days'));
//return '362 days'
```

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverFlow на русском! На этом сайте вопросы нужно задавать на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский язык., для этого нажмите "править" под вопросом. Если вы хотите задать вопрос на английском, то воспользуйтесь английским StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 2 ошибки в коде.
*Первая*: Пытались повторно объявить переменные `firstDate, secondDate`
*Вторая*: Для создания даты, необходимо передавать в конструктор значение, из которого будет формироваться дата `new Date(firstDate)`

```js
function durationBetweenDates(firstDate, secondDate, dimensionBetween) {
  const calcFirstDate = new Date(firstDate);
  const calcSecondDate = new Date(secondDate);
  const millisecondsDiff = calcSecondDate.getTime() - calcFirstDate.getTime();
  if (dimensionBetween === 'seconds'){
    const secondsType = millisecondsDiff / 1000;
    return secondsType;
  }
  if (dimensionBetween === 'minutes'){
    const minutesType = Math.ceil(millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 60));
    return minutesType;
  }
  if (dimensionBetween === 'hours'){
    const hoursType = millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 3600);
    return hoursType;
  }
  if (dimensionBetween === 'days'){
    const daysType = millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    return daysType;
  } else {
    return console.log('Not Found');
  }
  return durationBetweenDates;
}
console.log(durationBetweenDates('02 Aug 1985', '03 Aug 1985', 'seconds'));
//return '86400 seconds'
console.log(durationBetweenDates('31 Jan 2022', '03 Feb 2021', 'days'));
//return '362 days'
```

UPD:

Ваша функция в сокращенном варианте написания

```js
function durationBetweenDates(firstDate, secondDate, dimensionBetween) {
  const millisecondsDiff = new Date(secondDate).getTime() - new Date(firstDate).getTime();
  switch (dimensionBetween) {
    case 'seconds': return millisecondsDiff / 1000;
    case 'minutes': return Math.ceil(millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 60));
    case 'hours':   return millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 3600);
    case 'days':    return millisecondsDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    default:        return 'Not Found';
  }
}
console.log(durationBetweenDates('02 Aug 1985', '03 Aug 1985', 'seconds'));
//return '86400 seconds'
console.log(durationBetweenDates('31 Jan 2022', '03 Feb 2021', 'days'));
//return '362 days'
```